# Control the startup and monitoring GPIO status

Tags: gpio, boot, arduino

I want to control the startup of a Raspberry Pi 4 and at the same time listen to the GPIO status of the 40 pin. Can I use an Arduino for that? If so, any advice on which Arduino shall I use?

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor the Pi GPIO from an Arduino.

Note that all the Pi GPIO are 3V3 and there are 28 of them on the 40-pin expansion header.

You will need an Arduino with at least 28 GPIO if you want to monitor all the Pi GPIO simultaneously.  Although a 5V Arduino will probably see a Pi logic high 3V3 as high it might be safest to use a 3V3 Arduino.

Remember you must also connect the Arduino and Pi grounds.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you about an Arduino HAT that I can "plug" directly on top of Raspberry and suitable for that?

Comment: I found [this](https://www.robotshop.com/en/arduino-expansion-shield-raspberry-pi-b-23.html), for example. Will it be a good possibility?

Comment: Does that contain an Arduino?  Note that shopping advice is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry, forgot about that. In that case, can you advise any good introduction on how to read a schematic map?